# How to encode media in base64 given URL in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64, encode, activesupport

I'm trying to upload an image to PingFM. Their [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/pyngfm/) says:

```
media – base64 encoded media data.
```

I can access this image via the URL. I tried (practically guessed) this:

```
ActiveSupport::Base64.encode64(open("http://image.com/img.jpg"))
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: can't convert Tempfile into String
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/base64.rb:97:in `pack'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/base64.rb:97:in `encode64'
    from (irb):19
    from :0
```

Comment: I saw two answers! I wasn't able to get khelll's to work because, I suspect, I didn't understand it much. I'm picking mtyaka's because noobs like me can understand it easily.

Thanks to the both of you!

Comment: I know I'm commenting on a dead-ish question. But when you deal with base64 encoding media data out of a database, make sure it was sanitised going in or you build an injectable web-app.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The `open` method:

```
open("http://image.com/img.jpg")
```

is returning a Tempfile object, while `encode64` expects a String.

Calling `read` on the tempfile should do the trick:

```
ActiveSupport::Base64.encode64(open("http://image.com/img.jpg") { |io| io.read })
```

Comment: Please don't just .read, it will keep the file-descriptor open.
On 1.9, and I think with ActiveSupport, you can open(url, &:read), which will use the block form and close the file handle when done reading.
On vanilla 1.8, use open(url){|io| io.read } instead.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me but an Important note: You first need to require 'open-uri'. :D

Comment: You can do this: `ActiveSupport::Base64.encode64( open("http://image.com/img.jpg").read)` and you want to actually do at the end: `....g.jpg")read).gsub("\n", '')`

Answer (score 94):

To encode a file:

```
require 'base64'
Base64.encode64(File.open("file_path", "rb").read)
```

To produce the file from the encoded string:

```
require 'base64'
encoded_string = Base64.encode64(File.open("file_path", "rb").read)

File.open(file_name_to_create, "wb") do |file|
    file.write(Base64.decode64(encoded_string))
end
```

Comment: rails 4.0.1 // actually the one that works as ActiveSupport::Base64 returns an uninitialized constant, even from within a rails app (console)

Comment: This should be top-answer. Works without any gems, directly from ruby irb. (tested on ruby 2.0.0-p481)

Comment: Works. Without ActiveSupport. For me it's necessary to use 'rb' in File.open.

Comment: What is the purpose of the second argument to open ("rb") ?

Comment: @meetalexjohnson its the File open mode. `rb` meens `read as binary`. You can check docs for other modes as well

Answer (score 23):

This will work too, it's a little cleaner

```
 require 'base64'

 Base64.encode64(open("file_path").to_a.join)
```

"How do you decode this back into a file?" - @user94154

```
 require 'base64'

 open('output_file_name.txt', 'w') do |f| 
   f << Base64.decode64( encoded_content )
 end
```

Where `encoded_content` would be the previously encoded file content return value.

Comment: This answer isn't valid for later versions of Rails as it was removed after version 3.2.13 as stated in the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Base64/encode64s/class).

Comment: Thank you @RoopeHakulinen ! The answer has been updated to make use of just the ruby's Base64 implementation.

Answer (score 11):

Encode a file to base64 encoding:

```
File.open("output_file","w"){|file| file.write [open("link_to_file").string].pack("m")}
```

Decode base64 encoded file:

```
File.open('original', 'wb') {|file| file << (IO.readlines('output_file').to_s.unpack('m')).first }
```

Comment: in my case (ruby 2.0.0p481), `open("filename").string` fails with *NoMethodError: undefined method `string' for #<File:filename>*

Answer (score 5):

Here's my solution:

1: Put this custom image_tag method into ApplicationHelper, and include ActiveSupport module

```
module ApplicationHelper
  include ActiveSupport
  def image_tag_base64(file_path, mime_type = 'image/jpeg', options = {})
    image_tag("data:#{mime_type};base64,#{Base64.encode64(open(file_path) { |io| io.read })}", options)
  end
end
```

2: Then, inside the view you want to use base64 encoded image use the method like this:

```
<%= image_tag_base64 @model.paperclip_attribute.path(:size), @model.paperclip_attribute.content_type, {class: 'responsive-img etc etc'} %>
```

**3: DONE**

Answer (score -1):

In case it's useful to others, here's how to save a screenshot as base64 using `Watir`

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, {:chromeOptions => {:args => ['--headless', '--window-size=1000x1000']}})
browser.goto("http://www.yourimage.com")
browser.screenshot.base64
```

The beauty of this is you don't need to store the image itself