# Rails3 - pass thumbnail image as Byte Array to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, arrays

In Rails 3, how can I pass thumbnail image as Byte Array to JSON?

Comment: where is the image coming from? from a browser? with javascript, or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For converting images to text you could convert it to base64.

Check out:

ruby:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html

jquery:

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/base64

**UPDATE:**

[How to encode media in base64 given URL in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547008/how-to-encode-media-in-base64-given-url-in-ruby)

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html shows string and URL encode/decode only, not on image.

Comment: Base64.encode64 converts my image into the byte array that is not as expected. Would expect it to be in array of integers, such as this example: http://www.techques.com/question/1-10402834/NSData-to-byte-array-(or-array-of-integers). What decoder I should use?