# How to get an image from an HTTP request and still hide the source - Rails On Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, httprequest, src

I have to get an image from an HTTP request from the server side, then display it in my application via the web browser.

What is the best way to show the image without displaying the src url in the HTML (confidential url) ?

Thanks!

Comment: You could base64 encode the image. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547008/how-to-encode-media-in-base64-given-url-in-ruby) for details on how to do that.