# Full-page screenshot with URL in ruby ​and watir

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, watir

With the code below, I get a screenshot of only one part of the screen, but I would like to take a full screenshot, which shows the URL of the page as well.

**Is it possible?**

```
AfterStep do
  encoded_img = @browser.driver.screenshot_as(:base64)
    embed("data:image/png;base64,#{encoded_img}",'image/png')
end
```

Comment: A [watir-screenshot-stich](https://github.com/samnissen/watir-screenshot-stitch) gem was recently released to address a similar problem. You could see if that works for you.

Comment: The idea is good, but it still has not worked for me, I've read the documentation and applied it in my code, but it's still in the

Comment: I think you want to have a look at taking a screenshot from the OS point of view: For example for Windows https://github.com/jarmo/win32screenshot
The browser screenshot is limited to its viewport.

Comment: Hacky workaround, but you could use `browser.screenshot.save` with `browser.url` as the argument.  Admittedly, you'd have to do some gymnastics to strip `http://` and convert the `/` to another delimiter.  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Watir doesn't have this provision to capture the screenshot along with a URL. But we can use win32ole to do this.

```
require 'win32/screenshot'
```

Win32::Screenshot::Take.of(:desktop).write(image_path)

In my case for capturing the full-screenshot with a URL, I do the following

```
# Code to capture the full-page screenshot with a URL
require 'watir'
require 'win32ole'
require 'win32/screenshot'

# Launch a browser and navigate to the page
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
browser.goto "https://www.google.com"

win_title = browser.title #Fetch the Title

# Use AutoIt to get the focus of the browser to front
WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control").ControlFocus(win_title, "", "")

# Capture the screen shot of the desktop
sleep 2 # Hold for 2s
image_path = "image_path#{rand(10000)}.png"
Win32::Screenshot::Take.of(:desktop).write(image_path)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want `require 'win32/screenshot'`?

Comment: I tried to use it this way, what is the base 64 capture and then put it in the html status report, but without success.

 encoded_img = Win32 :: Screenshot :: Take.of (: foreground) .write (encoded_img)
  embed ("data: image / png; base64, # {encoded_img}", 'image / png')

Comment: I don't have knowledge in image format conversions. Whatever solution that I have provided to you will just give an output file in '.png' format, because your requirement is to capture a Full-page screenshot with URL. Either in selenium or in watir we don't have such support to capture the screenshot of a browser window. 

In case if you want to embed into page directly as base64, it's better to follow the steps:
1. Capture the image in a temporary location.
2. Convert it into base64
3. Embed into the page
4. If necessary delete the image file from the location.

Comment: Please have a look into the following URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547008/how-to-encode-media-in-base64-given-url-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

In my case for capturing the Full-screenshot with URL, I do the following

`#Code to capture the Full-Page screenshot with URL
require 'watir'
require 'win32ole'
require 'win32/screenshot'`

`#Launch Browser and navigate to page
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
browser.goto "https://www.google.com"`

`#Fetch the Title`
`win_title = browser.title`

`#Use AutoIt to get the focus of the browser to front`
`WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control").ControlFocus(win_title, "", "")`

`#Capture the screen shot of the desktop`
`sleep 2 # Hold for 2s
image_path = "image_path#{rand(10000)}.png"
Win32::Screenshot::Take.of(:desktop).write(image_path)`